# Getting a mysql thread id from sqlalchemy Session

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm used to creating connections using MySQLdb directly so I'm not sure this is at all possible using sqlalchemy, but is there a way to get the mysql connection thread id from a mysql Session a la MySQLdb.connection.thread_id()? I've been digging through and can't seem to find a way to access it. I'm not creating a connection from the Engine directly, and would like to avoid doing so.

For reference this is a single-thread application, I just need to get the mysql thread id for other purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

session.connection().connection.thread_id()